# innerHTML not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to display HTML code of a DIV element, `innerHTML` does not return its contents:

```
<div id="container">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">TEST</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

```js
var w = window.open();
w.document.write(data);
w.document.getElementById("prw").value = w.document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
w.document.close();
```

`prw` is an input element. `innerHTML` only returns `TEST`. Is there a way to copy HTML contents of a DIV without specifying TABLE element?

Comment: What is w here? Is it an iframe?

Comment: you are setting value not innerhtml

Comment: I'm setting value of an input field, I want it to contain HTML code of a div

Comment: If you are using jquery, why not don't you use jquery codes? It can make your codes standard!

Comment: `container` needs to be `table`. You can't use `tr` in non-table context.

Comment: Kermani can you please give me an example of jquery code in this specific case

Comment: for example, you don't need to say getElementById, jquery has css selectors, you could say `$("#prw")` and more ...

Comment: why are you closing the window before setting the value?

Comment: Jai i tried to close after but it gives the same problem

Comment: Emil Jorgensen is there a way to copy html code without specifying table element

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
<div id="container">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">TEST</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">TEST</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and this will work fine.

Comment: This works fine, but is there a way to copy that contents without specifying TABLE element?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, you should use OuterHTML instead of InnerHTML.

Comment: No, I need this to be in the input field:     <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">TEST</td>
    </tr>

Comment: This works but I have to add an id to the tr and place it into a table (it seems impossible to do it without specifying <table>) https://jsfiddle.net/dvqbo909/5/